# How to change the background color in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game using pygame and I am using rapidtables.com for this work but my game window is still not showing the required color. (It's showing but only when I close my game window). Here is my code-

```
#Space Invaders
from turtle import Screen, screensize
import pygame

#Intialize the game
pygame.init()  

#formation of screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#Title 
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

#Game loop
done = False  
  
while not done:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            done = True  
    pygame.display.flip()  

#RGB, Red, Green and blue
screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words: is `screen.fill((255, 0, 0))` inside the loop, or outside? How long do you expect the loop to run? Will `screen.fill((255, 0, 0))` happen while the loop is running? Therefore, when *will* it happen? Do you see why this causes a problem, given that that is the line of code with which you propose to change the background colour?

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and try to communicate clearly. Do not ask "how do I do X?" if you believe you have properly researched how to do X, written to code to do X, and the overall program doesn't work. You aren't really asking how to do X, and if you were, the correct answer would be that particular piece of code (here, `screen.fill((255, 0, 0))`). You are asking for *debugging help*, i.e. "why doesn't my code do X properly?".

Comment: When asking questions on Stack Overflow, you [should try to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For a debugging question, that means making your own attempt [at debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, try to be precise: if you want the screen to turn red, then don't say "the required color"; say "red" - and explicitly point at that `screen.fill` line and ask why *that* isn't doing the job.

Comment: Also: try to include all information that is relevant, but not anything else. I have never heard of "rapidtables.com", but it is only relevant if you believe it has something to do with the problem. To check: try using the code locally - does it work, or does it still have the same problem?

Comment: Thanks for help! I will follow the guidelines from now onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My game window is still not showing the required color (It's showing but only when I close my game window).

This is happening because you aren't changing the window color **inside** the game loop. The reason why you only see it when you close the game window is because when you close the window, the `pygame.QUIT` event is triggered. In your code, when that event is triggered, you set `done` to `True`, meaning the loop will stop running and the code outside of the loop will be executed. Since you are filling the window and updating the display outside of the loop, the screen only gets colored when the loop is no longer running (only when the `pygame.QUIT` event is triggered). So to fix that, move `screen.fill((255, 0, 0))` to inside your game loop.

### Modified Game Loop:

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # RGB, Red, Green and blue
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

I added `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit(0)` in order to quit the game and end the program (don't forget to add `import sys`).

## Full Code:

```
# Space Invaders
from turtle import Screen, screensize
import pygame
import sys

# Intialize the game
pygame.init()

# formation of screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Title
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

# Game loop
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # RGB, Red, Green and blue
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Man , This worked, I hope I find some good tutorials online related to python!

Comment: @DevanshiRathore, I'm happy to hear that :) Please accept the answer so that it can help other people who have the same issue.